# Firebase deletes the hole collection although specify the document id

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

iam using flutter and firebase to develop an app.

My Firebase collection/subcollection structure is the following:

collection(likes)-> doc(ownerId)->subcollection(likesList).doc(likeId){Data}

I wanna delete one like/doc out of the subcollection "likesList" using the likeId with this code:

```
final CollectionReference likesRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('likes');

Future deleteLike(String ownerId,String likeId)async{await likesRef.doc(ownerId).collection("likeList").doc(likeId).delete();}
```

This code deletes the complete likes-collection and i don`t understand why.

In my project are the latest package/flutter versions installed.

Let me know if i forget something,
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The code you shared deletes a single document based on the two IDs passed to it, not an entire collection. Can you edit your question to show how you determined that it does the latter?

Comment: But the collection disapears from firebase when i run this code.

Comment: If a collection is empty, it will be deleted by firestore. Is your collection empty after the document deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection can't exist without an document in it. So if you delete the last document in a collection, the collection is automatically removed. Maybe you are deleting the last document in the collection?

Comment: Hello, thats it, i wasn`t aware of this fact. Thank you for your help!